# ENTER handler in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm new in Google web toolkit. I should implement a button "enter key" in my project. Can you please help me?

In the login menu there is a click handler, on which the user enters her login information and be able to press "enter" afterward.

Code I have so far:

```
Button btnLogin = new Button("Login");
    btnLogin.addListener(new ButtonListenerAdapter() {
        public void onClick(Button button, EventObject e) {
            Date date = new Date();
            Cookies.setCookie("user", username.getValueAsString(), date);
            Cookies.setCookie("pass", password.getValueAsString(), date);               
            Cookies.setCookie("save_login", checkbox.getValueAsString(), date);

            formPanel.getForm().submit("Login", null, Connection.POST, "Logging...", false);
        }           
    });
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you please rephrase your question? It is hardly understandable. People will be more likely to help if the question is well written (they will take time for you if you took time for them) :)

Comment: now when i press with mouse log in i'm logged in,but i should do this and with ENTER button.write username,pass,hit enter and logged in

Answer (score 0):

If you like to submit the data , when the user uses the enter key, just add a KeyUpHandler to your button:

```
   button.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
        if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
          // do submit form
        }
      }
    });
```

You should use Handler instead of listener. Listener are old school and starting with GWT 2.0 deprecated.